# How to split python string into 2 variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm making a game in Pygame and I need to check the mouse position, I do this using

```
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

the variable ends up looking like `(x, y)` and I would like to turn each into its own variable. Originally, I was going to get the first 3 numbers and the last 3 numbers and split them up, however sometimes the coords drop to 2 digits and then it gets messed up because the integer has a comma in it. Any good way to fix this?

Comment: `x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()`? It's *not* a string, it's a *tuple*.

Comment: ...so use mouse[0] to access x and mouse[1] to access y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` will give you tuple, you can use tuple unpacking to get values in two variables

```
x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```